# Bulma - How to make text and image inline or next to each other?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am using Bulma for my project.

Basically, I am trying to put text and image(`height: 25em`) inline using Bulma. But it's not happening.

Up until now, I tried this:

```css
.img-cont {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

img {
  height: 25em;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: left;
}

.content {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container is-info">
  <div class="img-cont">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Pyp4DwX.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="content has-text-centered">
    <span class="title">MEDAL</span><br>
    <span class="subtitle">Loren Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And as you can see the text content doesn't get vertically centered and always stays at the bottom.

So, how can I fix this and achieve the look I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bulma is a Flexbox-based layout, so use the tools it provides you.
I've updated your snippet to include Bulma's [columns](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/). If you want them to stack on top of each other in a narrower viewport, remove the `is-mobile` class (see more [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/)).

```css
img {
  height: 25em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="columns is-mobile is-centered is-vcentered">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Pyp4DwX.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="title">MEDAL</span><br>
    <span class="subtitle">Loren Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```